# viewHolder cant view email but can't view name

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

The code below works for displaying emails, but it doesn't display anything else like name and goldar. Why is it like that?

This is the code

```
 private void updateList() {
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<information, listOnlineViewHolder>(
                information.class, R.layout.user_online,
                listOnlineViewHolder.class,
                counterRef) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final listOnlineViewHolder viewHolder, final information model, int position) {
                viewHolder.teksemail.setText(model.getEmail());
                viewHolder.namanya.setText(model.getNama());
                viewHolder.golongannya.setText(model.getGolDar());
      }
};
```

then, I tried the code like the one below he successfully displayed but the other list displays the name and the goldar,
while each email has a different name and goldar.

```
 private void updateList() {
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<information, listOnlineViewHolder>(
                information.class, R.layout.user_online,
                listOnlineViewHolder.class,
                counterRef) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final listOnlineViewHolder viewHolder, final information model, int position) {
                viewHolder.teksemail.setText(model.getEmail());
                //viewHolder.namanya.setText(model.getNama());
                //viewHolder.golongannya.setText(model.getGolDar());
               // Query userInfromation = databaseReference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(model.getEmail());
                databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                     // for (DataSnapshot posSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        //  information info = posSnapshot.getValue(information.class);
                            String name = dataSnapshot.child("nama").getValue(String.class);
                            String goldar = dataSnapshot.child("golDar").getValue(String.class);
                            viewHolder.namanya.setText(name);
                            viewHolder.golongannya.setText(goldar);
                            //}
                        }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

like this
[image]

I want to make each email display the name and goldar respectively, how is it done?[image]

Comment: please help me..

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Comment: like that sir??

Comment: How it `counterRef` defined?

Comment: counterRef will appear when there is a list that is online sir.

Comment: I'm sorry bit I cannot understand you. Can you please be more explicit?

Comment: counterRef will create a new child in the database with the name lastOnline and display the email and status. as shown below sir

Answer (score 0):

[image]

like that sir, like that sir, counterRef will display the online user in the database